# Differential of a function of matrices

Tags: differential-geometry

In a differential geometry exercise, I have to differentiate the following function:

$f:GL(2m,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathfrak{o}(2m)$, here $\mathfrak{o}(2m)$ denotes $2m\times 2m$ antisymmetric real matrices.

$f(A)=A^tJA-J$ where J is the canonical antisymmetric matrix.

The answer is: for any $A\in GL(2m,\mathbb{R})$, we have $df_A(B)=B^tJA+A^tJB=A^tJB-(A^tJB)^t$

I dont understand the differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

$f(A)$ is $g(A,A)-J$ where $g$ is the bilinear form defined by $g(A,B)=A^tJB$. So consider $h:Gl(2m,R)\rightarrow Gl(2m,R)\times Gl(2m,R)$ defined by $h(A)=(A,A)$, $f=g\circ h$. $dg_{A,B}(U,V)=U^tJB+A^tJV$ and $dh_A(W)=(W,W)$.

You can also compute the differential directly. $f(A+uB)-f(A)= (A+uB)^tJ(A+uB)-A^tJA= u(B^tJA+A^tJB)+u^2B^tJB=u(B^tJA+A^tJB)+O(u)$.

Comment: is it possible to understand it without using bilinear forms?

Comment: Your last term should be $O(u^2)$ or $o(u)$.